# Jquery mouseenter and mouseout animation

Tags: jquery

Im trying to do an event on mouseenter and mouseout.
If i put mouseover more than one time it will repeat the number of times i did it, even if still on first animation. Im also trying to stop the animation on mouseleave and animate it back.
Thanks in advance

Here's the javascript

```
$('.velejador').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.velejador').animate({
        left: '-=50',
        width: '40px'
      }, 2000);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.velejador').animate({
        left: '+=50',
        width: '40px'
      }, 2000);
});
```

Here the html

```
<div id="hidden-cartoons">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/cartoons/velejador.png' ?>" class="cartoon velejador">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/cartoons/bodoleite.png' ?>" class="cartoon bodoleite">
</div>
```

Comment: @JonnyDevv: On only 25% of your questions have you accepted an answer as correct.

Comment: ok my bad then.. going to review all the questions answered. i can only accept on answer right? Sorry all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSAjB/)

Two things, I've used `stop` to cancel any currently running animation. Second, I've replaced the '+=50' and '-=50' with absolute values because without those, if you keep mousing in and out, the div will end up moving further and further across the screen, which I assume isn't your objective.

Another thing to remember is, when do an animation on mouseenter that moves or resizes the element, you may potentially end up firing the mouseout event unless the user "chases" the element as you move it.

Comment: Thanks to your fiddle ive accomplished what i wanted.
http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyDevv/zSAjB/2/

Answer (score 3):

You can try this..

```
var velejador = $('.velejador');
var position = velejador.position();
velejador.mouseenter(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log(position);
    $this.css('left',position.left);
    $this.stop(1,0).animate({
        left: '-=50',
        width: '40px'
      }, 2000,function(){
        $this.stop(1,0).animate({
            left: '+=50',
            width: '40px'
        }, 2000);
      });       
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.velejador').mouseover(function() {
    $('.velejador').animate({
        left: '-=50',
        width: '40px'
    }, 2000);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $('.velejador').animate({
        left: '+=50',
        width: '40px'
    }, 2000).stop();
});
```

Depending on where the image is on "mouseout", you might want to use .css() to return the image to the original position.

Comment: Hmm it still queues the animations.
If i put mouseover 5 times when doing first animation, it does the animation more 5 times